# Qt ,C++ - Adding QDIR::Filters to directories and files

Tags: c++, qt4

I am trying to retrieve the files and directories in Qt using the QDir Filter. Based on the user input from the command line I plan to set the appropriate filters and retrieve the corresponding files.

User Input Eg: `./Retrieve  -d C:/Sample -h`

would retrieve me all the files including hidden files in the directory C:/Sample. I plan to give a host of other options like

`-h (for hidden files)
   -r (for readonly files)
  -s (for system files)`

currently my code is something like

> QDir::entryList(QDir::Dirs
>   |QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Hidden)

If I want to fetch even the system files I need to add just the `Qdir::system filter` . 
How can I append this to the existing filters I would have already mentioned.
My question is How do I add these filters to the QDir function entry List by having simple online code but build up the filters by looking at the user input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a three step process:

1. Define the flags that are the same regardless of user input, call it `filters` or something.
2. Iterate over the command line arguments and, when certain arguments are found, do a logical-OR of the appropriate QDir::Filter flag with `filters`
3. Keep going until all the cmdline arguments are dealt with.

`filters` now has all the filters the user requested.